# How to use custom input component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vue-quill-editor

While using Bootstrap-Vue as UI framework, I am trying to make a custom form component and use it in several parent components. Here is my form component

```
<template>
  <b-form>
    <b-input-group>
      <b-form-input placeholder="Post Title"></b-form-input>
      <wysiwyg-input placeholder="Post Content" />
    </b-input-group>
  </b-form>
</template>
```

and the parent component is

```
<FormFields :title="title" :content="content" />
```

How can i access the value in parent component from child component.

*Note: I am using vue-quill editor as well.*

Here is the codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benz-w8wgu?file=/src/App.vue

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Define a [`prop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) on your child component and pass the data to it when you use it in the parent:

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
export default {
  props: {
    someData: {}
  }
}
```

```js
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <child-component :some-data="myData"></child-component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myData: {...}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this method shows the following message in console.
"[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated"

Comment: It seems like you are mutating the prop in your child component. Try avoiding that. Otherwise, you have to use `.sync` modifier 
See this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: props should be immutable - i.e. "read-only".  if you need to update the value for some reason, either create a local copy of the prop data inside your child component, or `$emit` the updated value back to the parent for it to update the prop.